# Running linux command in Android app and reading output

Tags: java, android

How can I run a linux command from an Android App and read the output. For example: retrieving output of "ls -lh" and printing as a text in TextView?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
try{
                Process process;            
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -lh");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After this `in` post to your TextView.

Comment: I get this error: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command Working Directory: null Environment: null. Any idea whats this?